# Join subquery in Laravel model

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

*Please suggest a better title for this question. I have problems to name my question properly.*

## Background

I'm creating a comic database for personal use, to track my comic reads. Every comic belongs to a series. Every comics has a release date. The release date of a series is the first release of the according comic. I have a eloquent function `seriesByDate()` for that:

```php
class Series extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $primaryKey = 'series_id';
  protected $fillable = ['series_name', 'publisher_id'];

  public function publisher()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Publisher::class, 'publisher_id');
  }

  public function comics()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Comic::class, 'series_id', 'series_id');
  }

  // instead of saving the release date of a complete series
  // we look for the first comic in this series and get the
  // comic's release date.
  public static function seriesByDate()
  {
    $firstRelease = DB::table('comics')
      ->select('series_id', DB::raw('MIN(comic_release_date) as first_release'))
      ->groupBy('series_id');

    $seriesByDate = DB::table('series')
      ->leftJoinSub($firstRelease, 'first_release', function ($join) {
        $join->on('series.series_id', '=', 'first_release.series_id');
      })
      ->join('publishers', 'publishers.publisher_id', '=', 'series.publisher_id')
      ->select('series.series_id', 'series.series_name', 'first_release', 'publishers.publisher_name')
      ->get();

    return $seriesByDate;
  }
```

## What i want

I want the `release_date` somehow be permanent to my Series model. Meaning: When I do a `App\Series::all()` i already want to have the release_date as a column in my returned data. Similar to `App\Series::with('publishers')->get()`

With my solution above i have to eplicitly execute `App\Series::seriesByDate()`

Is this even possible? Can you please give me a hint?

## Edit / Update

The linked video by @Musa shows how to properly do this in a model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558482/5754486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't. There is no magic for this. You might eventually write your own custom Relation but that would be unnecessarily complex, just for the sake of having a pretty `related`/accessor. Both solutions are not great performance-wise.
- Not sure why you choose such a structure. Without any further context/explanation, I would strongly recommend you to have a `release_date` column directly inside your `Series` model as well. That will be waaaay faster than your current structure.
- If you still want to stick with that structure, I would personally retrieve the `release_date` "php side" instead of "database side" :

```
$series = App\Series::query()
    ->with([
        'publishers',
        'comics' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at');
        },
    ])
    ->get();

foreach ($series as $serie) {
    $serieTitle = $serie->title;
    $releaseDate = $serie->comics->first()->created_at;

    echo $serieTitle.' was first released '.$releaseDate->diffForHumans().'<br/>';
}
```

(not tested)
the only downside is that it will return a Collection of every "comics" a "serie" has. If you do not have 10k comics per serie and you do not load 1k serie per page, that should be fine. In any case, this looks more elegant and optimized/faster than your `seriesByDate` method.

edit: also, you should watch "Advanced Querying With Eloquent" by Jonathan Reinink, at Laracon 2018 I believe. He discusses subqueries like the one you need. I am 100% sure you will find the best and most optimal Eloquent subquery one can forge for what you are trying to achieve : https://vimeo.com/showcase/7060635/video/255049572

Comment: Valid point. My idea was, that i never have to care about the release date of a series. If i have a second column `release_date` i need an extra logic for keeping the comics.release_date and series.release_date updated. Thanks for the video. I'm going to watch it.

Comment: You might consider having a Model Observer on the ```Comic``` model in that case. It would update the ```release_date``` column automatically for you on the ```Series``` model, every time you perform a create/update on the ```Comic``` model, depending on your own logic. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers

Comment: Actually the linked video is great and it exactly shows a solution for my use case. My basic idea was not wrong, just executed poor :-) Reinink also builds a subselect, eager load it and use a scope to bind it to the model. Really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can defined an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators) then append the value

```
class Series extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['series_date'];

    public function getSeriesDateAttribute()
    {
        return self::seriesByDate();
        //OR build 'seriesByDate' manually, returning whatever you like.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very promising, but what am I doing wrong? 

`protected $appends = ['test_var'];

  public function getTestVarAttribute() { return "hi"; }`

Comment: It seems like the `$appends` is being ignored/unused. Output from tinker shell: `>>> App\Series::get()[0]
=> App\Series {#3224
     series_id: 1,
     series_name: "Batman",
     publisher_id: 1,
   }`

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't appear in tinker even if I use `toArray`. maybe this because tinker always return the model instance. if you not sure its been added to the append list just try `toArray` or `toJson` it should be visible

Comment: Actually this is also a valid solution. Thanks. Just my way of doing this nasty join/subqueries is messy.